# How to add new item to asyncio queue as soon as a slot is available?

Tags: python, join, download, queue, python-asyncio

This code works like this:

List named 'ids' contains id numbers. By id numbers I download specific messages.
'nDownload' is the list index. The size value of the queue is equal to 5.

I pick up item from list ,download message one at time and add it to queue.
When nDownload is equal to 6 :

1. QueueFull exception occours.
2. Create 5 workers.
3. Workers extract metadata from message for other purposes.
4. await queue.join() Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.
5. End -> delete workers.

The code works, I have no issue until now.

```
                nDownload = 0
                workers = []
                while (nDownload <= len(ids)):                        
                    try:
                        async for msg in get_messages(channel,ids=ids[nDownload]):
                           nDownload = nDownload + 1
                            try:   
                                queue.put_nowait(msg)
                            except (asyncio.QueueFull,IndexError) as qErr:
                                nDownload = nDownload - 1 
                                workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(queue)) for _ in range(5)] 
                                await queue.join() 
                                for cancel in workers:
                                    cancel.cancel()                                    
                    except IndexError as iErr:
                        break
```

Question:
Sometimes message has different size. For example :

message 1 =  100MB  downloaded in 8 minutes

message 2 =  1MB  downloaded in  5 seconds

Once it has downloaded the shortest message (message 2) , I get a free 'slot' in queue.
Unfortunately, I have to wait for message 1 because queue.join()

How do add new item to queue at that time?

Why Do I use queue.join() ?
Because I dont know how to add max 5 messages to queue, wait for download it and resume
I really need download group of messages and not all at once
Thanks

EDIT :
Yes, my worker is defined like this (simplified)

```
async def worker(queue):
while True:
    queue_msg = await queue.get()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        task = loop.create_task(extract(queue_msg))
        await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=timeout)

    except errors.Fail:
  #Here I have to requeue the message when it fails,
  #so it requeues the ID in order to download the same msg later
     await queue.put(queue_msg.id)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError: 
     #requeue the msg etcc...

    finally:    
        queue.task_done()
```

Your answer is very smart, thanks
However I choose queue 'size > 1' because I need to refetch the message when it fails the 'extract' task. ( sry I didn't tell you)
I do not know what's going to happen if queue size = 1 and I try to add item. It's a bit hard this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what your constraints are, but if I understand you correctly:

- you want to download at most 5 things in parallel
- you don't want to waste time - as soon as a worker is done with an item, it should obtain a new one

The queue size should be irrelevant for your purposes, it only serves as a buffer in case the workers are temporarily faster than `get_messages`. I'd even start with a queue size of 1 and experimented with whether larger values help with performance.

Spawning tasks on `QueueFull` seems strange and unnecessary. The idiomatic way to approach a producer-consumer pattern is to create a fix number of consumers and have them process multiple items as they arrive. You didn't show `worker` so it's not clear whether each worker processes just one message, or multiple ones.

I would rewrite the loop as:

```
queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(queue)) for _ in range(5)]
for current in ids:
    async for msg in get_messages(channel, id=current):
        # enqueue msg, waiting (if needed) for a free slot in the queue
        await queue.put(msg)
# wait for the remaining enqueued items to be processed
await queue.join()
# cancel the now-idle workers, which wait for a new message
# that will never arrive
for w in workers:
    w.cancel()
```

A worker would be defined like this:

```
async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        msg = await queue.get()
        ... process msg ...
        queue.task_done()
```

Comment: Thanks user4815162342, I always read your answer on stackoverflow. I edited my answer

Comment: @doubleme You can enqueue stuff from workers, they'll just wait for a free slot - but you do open yourself for the possibility of deadlock the queue is full and all workers decide to requeue. The simplest solution is to make the queue unbounded - if the number of messages is finite, that should work fine as well, and `await queue.put(...)` will simply never block.